# How to avoid creating object of classA in ClassB

Tags: java

I had a question in one of my interview:

Let's say I have a classA and I should create object of classA in only classA not in any other class, for example:

```
classA{
// some instructions

ClassA a = new ClassA();
}

ClassB{
//Some instructions

ClassA a1 = new ClassA(); // Here I should throw a compilation or runtime error.
}
```

I told by adding private constructor, but he told that we should have a capability of creating more than once object with in the same class. Can I make this?

Comment: Make the constructor private.

Comment: Note that compilation errors are *vastly* preferable to runtime errors.

Comment: I told the same, but the interviewer told that, we should have ability to create more than one object in same class.

Comment: @user8579908 then your interviewer doesn't know what he is talking about. Making a constructor private has nothing to do with the number of instances that can be created.

Comment: @AndyTurner Either that or it is a trick question to see if OP knows what he is talking about and "private constructor" is not just a wild guess :D.

Comment: @user8579908 "I told like make the class as a singleton class by adding private constructor" Ah, well, there's the source of the confusion: *you* introduced the word singleton here; whilst private constructors are necessary for (non-enum) singletons, they are used in other circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

Make its constructor `private`:

```
private classA() {}
```

This forbids to invoke it anywhere else.

E.g. private constructors are used for [Utility classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223553/how-can-i-create-an-utility-class) or [Static factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods)

 **UPDATE:** As @Arkadiy noticed it doesn't limit amount of instances you can create.

Comment: I told the same, but the interviewer told that, we should have ability to create more than one object in same class.

Comment: So edit your question properly.

Comment: private constructor does not preclude more than one instance. The interviewer was mixing up private constructor with the singleton pattern. Private constructor is  used to implement singleton pattern, but can be used in other circumstances.

Comment: Maybe it was the Static Factory pattern required by interviewer? That pretty much only allows creation of the object inside the class, BUT it also allows access to the method that does the task from outside. Not the easiest question for a junior programmer I guess.

Comment: @Vlasec I guess we shouldn't divine what interviewer said, since OP more likely has misunderstood him.

Comment: Yep, if what OP said was true and exact, the interviewer would be an incompetent person. It's more likely that OP is just a bit too green to get it.

Comment: By the way, private constructors are used in more cases than you mentioned, and in utility classes it is only to prevent instantiation completely :)

Comment: @Vlasec unfortunately nobody will know. btw It's far not the first question like this, where everebody are so interested what interviewer has asked, but OP just intrigued everybody and can't explain correctly.

Comment: @Vlasec right. Obviously I just meant that in these examples private constructors are used as a part of entire realization.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it happen by using private access modifier to constructor of the class,

private access modifier only let private things access with in it own class.

Following is table of access modifiers and their access scopes 
[image]

Comment: This code is not relevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

1. make the constructor private
2. follow a factory method or factory pattern